# Finding probability using normal approximation

Tags: probability

The probability distribution of point S at a time is P(S=8)=0.01, P(S=9)=0.29, P(S=10)=0.70.

How to find the probability that total points in ten independent times is less than 96 points using normal approximation?

I tried by multiplying the expected value of S by 10 and variance by 100 since it is 10 times. Then let Y, the total score to be normally distributed with mean of 96.9 and variance of 23.39. But I still can't get the answer state in  the book. Maybe my method is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've got 10 realizations of $S$, name them
\begin{equation}
 S_1 \ldots S_{10}
\end{equation}
Let's consider 
$X = \frac{S_1 + \ldots + S_{10}}{10}$
We are interested in the probability of 
\begin{equation}
 Pr(X \leq \frac{96}{10}) = Pr(X \leq 9.6)
\end{equation}
Sine $S_i$'s are i.i.d, then by the Central Limit Theorem, we have that 
\begin{equation}
 \sqrt{10} (X - \mu) \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)
\end{equation}
where $\mu = E(S_i)$ and $\sigma^2 = var(S_i)$. 
\begin{align}
 \mu &= 8(Pr(S = 8)) + 9(Pr(S=9)) + 10(Pr(S = 10))\\
 &=
 8(0.01) + 9(0.29) + 10(0.7)\\
 &=
 9.69
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
 \sigma^2 &= E(S_i^2) - \mu^2\\
 &=
  8^2(Pr(S = 8)) + 9^2(Pr(S=9)) + 10^2(Pr(S = 10))- 9.69^2\\
  &=
  8^2(0.01) + 9^2(0.29) + 10^2(0.7) - 9.69^2 \\
  &=0.2339
\end{align}
So now all you have to do is standardize $X$
\begin{equation}
 Pr(X \leq 9.6) 
 =
 Pr(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \leq \frac{9.6 - 9.69}{0.2339}
 )
\end{equation}
Note that $Z = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is standard normal so
 \begin{equation}
 Pr(X \leq 9.6) 
 =
 Pr(Z\leq \frac{9.6 - 9.69}{0.2339}
 = Pr(Z \leq - 0.38)
\end{equation}
Now, you can use the z-table to find your probability.